# subset datatable by column

Tags: python, datatable, py-datatable

Trying to subset a datatabl a couple different ways:

```
DT1 = dt.Frame(A=range(5))

DT1[f.A > 2] ## select rows where A greater than 2

DT1[DT1['A'] > 2] ## select rows where A greater than 2

DT1[DT1['A'] in 2] ## select rows where A equal to 2
```

However getting errors on all of these.

What would the correct syntax be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select rows of a Frame based on some condition, then the syntax for that is

```
DT1[f.A > 2, :]
```

So, what you have written is almost correct, except that it misses the column selector part `:`.

You can check the tutorial for different kinds of column/row selection at https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/select_and_filter_data.html

Comment: thanks. is there anyway to subset with `.isin` ?

Comment: Not at the moment, but someone is already working on that feature: https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/699